# GGally putPlot does not work in loop

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am trying to use putplot to change the plots on the diagonal of a ggpairs plot. I can do this one by one, but when I use a loop the diagonal elements are the same!

```
library(ggplot2)
library(GGally)

p=ggpairs(iris, 
    columns=, c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width"),
    colour='Species',
    lower=list(continuous='points'), 
    axisLabels='none',  
    upper=list(continuous='blank')
)

for (i in 1:4) {
    p <- putPlot(p, ggplot(iris, aes(x=iris[,i], colour=Species)) + stat_ecdf(), i,i)
}
print(p)
```

[image: Non working example]

Unwinding the loop works... why...?

```
p <- putPlot(p, ggplot(iris, aes(x=iris[,1], colour=Species)) + stat_ecdf(), 1,1)
p <- putPlot(p, ggplot(iris, aes(x=iris[,2], colour=Species)) + stat_ecdf(), 2,2)
p <- putPlot(p, ggplot(iris, aes(x=iris[,3], colour=Species)) + stat_ecdf(), 3,3)
p <- putPlot(p, ggplot(iris, aes(x=iris[,4], colour=Species)) + stat_ecdf(), 4,4)
```

[image: Working example]

Comment: Thank you for the edit @Llopis, I didn't have enough rep to do it myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the result of so-called lazy evaluation in `ggplot`. The calls to the various `ggplot` functions do not actually create a plot, they define how the plot is to be rendered. The plot is only created with, e.g., `print(p)`.

The issue is that the arguments to `aes(...)` are stored as *expressions* in the plot definition, and those expressions are only evaluated when you render the plot. So in your case the four calls to `ggplot` are all stored the same way, with `x=iris[,i]`. When you render the plot, `i=4` and all four diagonal slots are rendered with `x=iris[,4]`.

So how to deal with this? We have to put the definition of `x` outside the call to `aes(...)`. This code accomplishes that:

```
for (i in 1:4) {
  p <- putPlot(p,ggplot(data=data.frame(x=iris[,i],Species=iris$Species), 
                        aes(x=x,colour=Species)) + stat_ecdf(), i,i)
}
print(p)
```

Here we are setting the default dataset for `ggplot` to a different data frame in each plot using  the appropriate column of iris for x. The reason this works is that the refenrece to `x=iris[,i]` is *not* in the call to `aes(...)`.

See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22251928/list-of-plots-using-lapply) for a closely related problem, with a nearly identical solution.

Comment: _Very_ nicely explained. Thank you!