# List of plots using lapply

Tags: r, ggplot2, lapply

I have been using lapply and sapply as my go-to functions recently. So far so good, but why the following code does not work baffles me.

```
df<-as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(50),ncol=5))
names(df)<-c("x1","x2","x3","x4","x5")
df1<-seq_len(10)

ll<-lapply(seq(1,5), function(i) qplot(df1,df[,i]))
```

I get the error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(df, , i) : undefined columns selected
```

Ok, apparently I made quite an unfortunate mistake in my reproducible code. It works now, but all the plots in the `ll` list are the same plot. When I run this:

`do.call(grid.arrange,ll)`

I get the following image:

[image: Grid]

All the plots are the same! This is also the output I get when I run this through my data.

Comment: What error does it give you?

Comment: Added it into the answer.

Comment: Given the example plot you posted, I would not use `grid.arrange`, but switch to using facetting (`facet_wrap` or `facet_grid`). See my answer for an example. Facetting is much easier and flexible in my opinion.

Comment: Yes, I knew about facetting but didn't think of it here. Thanks for the suggestion. But I still want to find out why this code is giving me 5 identical plots.

Comment: See @BrodieG's answer, it is related to lazy evaluation.

Comment: Any info about the lazy evaluation thing? I want to avoid this for future loops.

Comment: I added a section to my answer which explains lazy evaluation in the context of your example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are problems with lazy evaluation, or something like it anyway.  You need to do the following:

```
ll<-lapply(
  seq(1,5), 
  function(i) qplot(data=data.frame(y=df[, i]), df1, y)
)
```

This will force the y values to be updated for each plot.

More discussion in this other **[SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7041204/pass-by-value-in-r)**.

Comment: +1! Or skip the looping entirely, and use facetting. This is how `ggplot2` was designed.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra, I agree, though there are some circumstances where lists of ggplot plots are actually a useful thing, but you're probably right that in this case the facetted approach is the better outcome.

Answer (score 5):

The problem you get is related to lazy evaluation. This means that the functions in `ll` are only really evaluated when you call them, which is in `grid.arrange`. At that time, each function will try and locate `i`, which will have a value of `5` by that time because that is the last value of `i` at the end of the `lapply` loop. Therefore, the data extracted from `df` is always the fifth column, thus your plots are all equal.

To prevent this, you need to force the data extraction to take place when the function is created, for example using @BrodieG's method. There, a new `data.frame` is created, forcing the data from `df` to be picked up. Alternatively, you can use `force` to force the evaluation of `i`.

See also for more examples and explanations of lazy evaluation:

- [variable-scope in R functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628656/variable-scope-in-r-functions)
- [Explain a lazy evaluation quirk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129902/explain-a-lazy-evaluation-quirk)

---

For creating plots of multiple columns in the same data.frame I would use `facet_wrap`. To use `facet_wrap`, you need to reorder your data using `melt` from the `reshape2` package:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
df$xvalues = 1:10
df_melt = melt(df, id.vars = 'xvalues')
ggplot(df_melt, aes(x = xvalues, y = value)) + 
    geom_point() + facet_wrap(~ variable)
```

[image]

Comment: This is indeed a better solution since it allows me to use the more elegant `ggplot` + `ggsave` combo rather than the `qplot` + `grid.arrange` mess. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I've rarely had to resort to using a loop, facetting can almost always be used to get the same result.

Answer (score 3):

You are telling it to execute for 10 columns where you only have 5. This works:

```
ll<-lapply(seq(1,5), function(i) qplot(df1,df[,i]))
```

Comment: Thanks. I have edited my initial post as I'm now seeing the same issue as in my dataset.